# Negotiating a 'final offer'

Tags: job-offer, new-job, united-states

I have a question about offer negotiation. I was caught of guard by a recruiter today, and when he called to tell me that they extend the offer to me I asked if it is a final offer. He said it is their best offer. The issue is, it is 25% lower than my another offer that they know about (it is in a location with lower cost of living). I said I will review the package and let them know.

I am interested in working for this big company, but can't take such a pay cut. How should I approach it? If the recruiter say the offer is final should I just decline at that point? 
I would appreciate any help

Comment: Send them your "final offer".

Comment: I think the sense of your question is:  "does the phrase best offer mean anything?"  The answer is no, it means nothing.  Absolutely nothing.

Comment: So even thought they say it's their best, I'm  not risking anything by asking?

Comment: @Dany What would you risk by asking?  Even if they didn't raise it and you ended up taking it at 25% lower than the alternative, I can't see where there is a risk in asking for more

Answer (score 7):

> I am interested in working for this big company, but can't take such a
>   pay cut. How should I approach it?

Give it one final shot.

Determine the amount it would take to convince you to join. Then tell them pretty much exactly what you wrote. Finally, add the amount that would make you satisfied.

"I am interested in working for this company, but can't take such a big pay cut. If they would agree to $X, then I'd accept."

If they cannot meet your requirement, thank them for their consideration and move on to another job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Do companies say that it's their best but leave some room for negotiation just in case? Sorry Im a newbie in the job market :D